# Singleton Bean Lock Type Inheritance

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly

i got a Singleton Bean which inherits from an Abstract Bean. My Singleton Bean is annotated with @LockType(READ) and i want the annotation to apply also to the inherited methods from the Abstract Bean.

Somebody knows how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate your Abstract parent class also with @Lock(LockType.READ), this should solve your problem.